# Enterprise App distribution Query

Tags: iphone

I have developed an Enterprise application and distributed it to one of my colleague for testing along with the `".app"` and the distribution provisioning profile.

If I want to put this app on my website, how can I ensure the app can only be downloaded by registered users and cannot be distributed?

Is there any other way to restrict the distribution of my app?

Thanks in advance,

Amit

Answer (score 1):

The provisioning file limits the devices that the application can be installed on.

Edit: at least assuming the device isn't jailbroken. I don't know if it is possible to bypass this on a jailbroken phone, but I would assume so.

Comment: what is the no. of devices on which i can install the enterprise application ? Bcos i think my inhouse application can be distributed to all inhouse emplyees isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add device ID's on your development portal - the distribution certificate you create should only work for the devices you used to make that provisioning profile.

Anyone using a device not in that list will not be able to install the application.

Comment: I think we do not have to add the Device IDs any where for application made using Enterprise License, i have tested this. I have distributed .app + provisioning profile to the iPhone's those are not added to the protal and still they are able to run the application. I think you are talking about adhoc distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The Enterprise Program allows you to distribute to anyone in your particular corporation (minimum size 500 employees).

I'm assuming the Enterprise Program EULA restricts you to 'in house' use only, and any further distribution would be grounds for them to revoke your account and maybe sue you too.

It is up to you to ensure the application does not get distributed more widely, I'm guessing you really shouldn't be putting it up on a public website for anybody to download.  If you want anybody to download it you should be publishing a free app on the App Store using the Standard Program account.